# Discover when the user closes the preferences activity

Tags: android

I know it may sound silly, but I really cannot understand if there is a straightforward and standard way to understand when a user gets out from the preferences activity.

```
case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Pref.class); startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateData();
        return true;
```

Obviously here the "test" Toast appears asynchronously, while the preferences window is still open. But in the preferences the user could change vital parameters that, to be applied, need updateData() to be called: how can I do? I'm sure that there's a obvious way to do it, but I'm missing it....
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `startActivityforResult` instead of startActivity and show the toast in  `onActivityResult`

Comment: That's good, I didn't know about that, thanks, but I see that it's available only since API 16, is there a more retro-compatible solution?

Comment: its available since api level 1, where did you see that its available only in api 16

Comment: Uuuh no... thanks very much.
It's available since API 1. The same function with the Bundle parameter is available since API 16. Thank you, this give me the solution :)